# Android device detection in Lenovo yoga laptop - Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, usb, android, lenovo

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit edition onto this laptop that is UEFI/Win8 specialized by default. Everything was working fine until I tried plugging in an Android device. The device won't get detected. I have tried following.

```
:~$ lsusb

:~$ sudo apt-get install mtpfs
:~$ sudo apt-get install jmtpfs
```

Neither of them made any difference. The USB is not fully supported for other OS in this laptop, I have come to a conclusion. This really gives me a gutted feeling, as I wanted Ubuntu on this so bad.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, all I did was use a high quality USB cable which fixed it. Silly how such simple things make a huge difference.